# Python3 variables in functions

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x, global-variables

```
def a():
    b = 1
    def x():
        b -= 1
    if something is something:
        x()
a()
```

What im wanting here is to change `b` from `a()` in `x()`
I have tried using;

```
def a():
    b = 1
    def x():
        global b
        b -= 1
    if something is something:
        x()

a()
```

But this, as I expected, this told me global b is not defined.

`b` needs to change after `x()` is has run and if `x()` is called a second time `b` needs to be what `x()` set it to - 0 not what it was originally set to in `a()` - 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to alter the value of a variable defined in a containing scope, use `nonlocal`.  This keyword is similar to intent to `global` (which indicates the variable should be considered to be the binding in the global scope).

So try something like:

```
def a():
    b = 1
    def x():
        # indicate we want to be modifying b from the containing scope
        nonlocal b
        b -= 1
    if something is something:
        x()

a()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate at all on what non local is exactly. Very new to Python (well programming in general)

Comment: Than you, that explanation was perfect

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def a():
    b = 1
    def x(b):
        b -= 1
        return b
    b = x(b)
    return b
a()
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for a way to do it without using 'return'